# Passing arguments from method to method doesn't seem to change the agrument in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, arguments, parameter-passing, this

I'm working on a card game in `typeScript`.
The game does somthing like this:

```
game = () => {
let get_start_card = () => {
  let card:string
  // get random card ...
  return card
}
let start_round = (player:Player,card:string) => {
  console.log(`card at start is: ${card}`)
  // some logic ...
  // change the card - generate new_card
  this.start_card = new_card
}
let game_status: boolean = true
let start_card = get_start_card()

while(game_status === true){
  start_round(player1,start_card)
  start_round(player2,start_card)
}
}
game()
```

The idea is that when the next turn starts, the next player start with the card that the other player left at the end of his turn.

The problem is that the `start_round` method allways start with the original card, and doesn't seem to change, when I write `this.start_card` or `this.this.start_card` or anything else.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

I the way I try to change the value of `start_card` before the next round using the keyword "`this`" is wrong?

What is the correct way to do such thing, OOP-wise?

Edit: removing "this" results in an error, not recognizing "start_card".

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It should be without `this`.

```
start_card = new_card
```

The OOP way would be to use a class, then you would use `this` a lot. You've made a closure instead, and `start_card` is a regular variable, not a property of anything.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I remove the "this" VSCode flags an error: cannot find  name "start_card"